# Django template iterating a queryset with a for loop counter

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 3 query sets for 3 different types of articles: Right leaning, center, left leaning. I am trying to display these in 3 columns so it would come out as:

Right Lean | Center Lean | Left Lean

Right Lean | Center Lean | Left Lean

Right Lean | Center Lean | Left Lean

So, I have these in three query sets, like this in the view:

```
right_articles = sline.article_set.filter(avgLean__lte=-0.75).order_by('-credibility')[:25]
left_articles = sline.article_set.filter(avgLean__gte=0.75).order_by('-credibility')[:25]
center_articles = sline.article_set.filter(avgLean__gt=-0.75).filter(avgLean__lt=0.75).order_by('-credibility')[:25]
```

And I added a counter for how many I want in each column as part of the context like this:

```
return render(request, 'storylines/detail.html', {'n_articles': range(0, 24),
        'storyline': sline, 
        'reqUser':request.user, 
        'vote':ini, 'right_articles':right_articles, 
        'left_articles': left_articles, 
        'center_articles': center_articles})
```

Then I go to the template and loop through those like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class= "col-4">
    Left articles: {{ left_articles.count }}
</div>
<div class= "col-4">
    Center articles: {{ center_articles.count }}
</div>
<div class= "col-4">
    Right articles: {{ right_articles.count }}
</div>
</div>
    {% for i in n_articles %}
   <div class="row">
        Trying {{ i }}<br>
        {% with left_articles.i as lt_article %}
            {% if lt_article %}
                {% show_card lt_article %}
            {% else %}
                <div class="col-4">No Left article {{ i }}</div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}

        {% with center_articles.i as cn_article %}
            {% if cn_article %}
                {% show_card cn_article %}
            {% else %}
                <div class="col-4">No Center article {{ i }}</div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}

        {% with right_articles.i as rt_article %}
            {% if rt_article %}
                {% show_card rt_article %}
            {% else %}
                <div class="col-4">No Right article {{ i }}</div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    </div>      
    {% endfor %}
```

The count statements on the first row shows that I do in fact have 1 each left/center/right. If I modify my code to replace right_articles.i with right_articles.0, I get an article. The line that says Trying {{ i }} shows that i starts at 0, so right_articles.i should return an article when i = 0. However, unfortunately, I get no articles, which means that I have something wrong with the syntax of

```
        {% with right_articles.i as rt_article %}
```

Can anyone tell me the right way to say what I'm trying to say here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not suggest anything to improve, a custom tag filter will do the trick:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def select_item(queryset,i):
    return queryset[i]
    # Be careful of IndexError: list index out of range
```

So now, you will have access to the item

```
{% with left_articles|select_item:i as lt_article %}
{% endwith %}
```